# Inequality greater than 1

Tags: derivatives, inequality

I want to show that for $s\in(0,\frac{t}{2})$, $t$ positiv, holds that

$\frac{t^{(t-s)/t}(s+1)}{t-s}>1$

I have already tried to reason about the zeros and derivative, but come to no result.

Define the function $n(s,t)=\frac{t^{(t-s)/t}(s+1)}{t-s}-1$.
The Statement follows when $s=0$ is a zeroes and the derivative $n'$ is positiv on $[0,\frac{t}{2}]$.

It holds that $n(0,t)=0$ and it remains to show that for the derivative holds:
$\frac{t^{-s/t}((s+1)(s-t)\log(t)+t(t+1))}{(t-s)^2}>0$

At this point I do not get further :)

Comment: With zeroes and derivatives you shoud be able to solve this problem. Show us what you've tried and then we can see what are your problems and help you.

Comment: I edited the derivative

Answer (score 1):

Let $s = rt$ for some $r \in (0, 1/2)$. Then $$\frac{t^{(t-s)/t}(s+1)}{t-s} = \frac{t^{1-r}(rt + 1)}{t(1-r)} = \frac{t^{-r}(1+rt)}{1-r}.$$
By [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality), we know $1 + rt \geq (1 + t)^r$. Hence,
$$\frac{t^{-r}(1+rt)}{1-r} \geq \frac{t^{-r}(1+t)^r}{1-r} \geq \frac{t^{-r}\cdot t^r}{1-r} = \frac{1}{1-r} > \frac{1}{1-0} = 1.$$
This proves the inequality.

*Remark*: The inequality still holds true even if $s \in (0, t)$ (which is equivalent to $r \in (0, 1)$).